# Create baseline table in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a table of baseline characteristics of trial participants, along with randomised group. All the characteristics are categorical. Is there a nice way that I can create a table of summary statistics by group?

I can do it using:

```
proc freq data = clean.rand_tiny;
    tables (age_cat bmi4cat prev_preg prev_exposure periods_6m) * (Trt_1 Trt_2) / nopercent norow;
run;
```

but it gives me a separate table for each variable and it would be nice to have it all together as one table to make exporting to a report easier.

Comment: Please post sample data in `datalines` or a table format so that we can help.

Comment: Check out PROC TABULATE.

Comment: See this page. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Demographic-Table-and-Subgroup-Summary-Macro-TABLEN/ta-p/634030

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to get the output you want directly out of proc freq.

The best approach will probably be to create an output dataset and display that dataset with proc print. Or proc report/tablulate (if you want to make it pretty).

Something along the lines of this:

```
proc freq data=xxx noprint;
  tables ...;
  output out=counts n=n ... ;
run;

proc print data=counts;
run;
```

or

```
proc report data=counts;
 ...
run;
```

[proc freq](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#freq_toc.htm)

[output statement](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_freq_sect009.htm)

[proc report](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000068725.htm)